# PC Excel macros doesn't work on Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel, macros

I wrote a macros that removes all the non-numeric characters from the logistics code and multiplies numbers left.  On the pc it's okey, on my mac it doesn't work.

Here the code, probably someone could suggest me why the macros doesn't work on mac:

```
   Function Bek(s)
Static re As Object
Dim x
  If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "[0-9.,]+"
    re.Global = True
  End If
  If re.test(s) Then
    Bek = 1
    For Each x In re.Execute(s)
      Bek = Bek * Val(Replace(x, ",", "."))
    Next
  End If
End Function
```

I could also attach a file upon your request.

P.S. found some information, that the regexp might not be supported by mac os.

Very appreciate your help.

Comment: Andreas, probably you're right, but it would better if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: If you would give us input data and expected output, we can help you but now it's a bit unclear.

Comment: So I've got some codes like: S10 2000*6000, 114,3*6,3. The macros removes all the non-numeric symbols, like S,*,space, and multiplies all those numbers left: 10x2000x6000.  On pc is just fine, on mac it doesn't, I suppose due to unsupported regexp or something else.

Comment: @andreas You are obviously wrong, at least as far as most things including support costs go. But you would be right if you restricted your use of Macs to using Microsoft Software, especially Excel. Excel has ranged from being better on a mac (where it was first developed) to being almost non-functional (Excel 2016 has no VBE for editing macros!!! but previous version was mostly OK).

Comment: Your macro fails because the VBscript regular expression library is not available on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It splits and looks at each part of the string and handles it the way I think you want.
Try it and see if it works

```
Sub ApplesWayOfRegex()


    Str1 = "S10 2000*6000"

    ReDim chars(Len(Str1) - 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(Str1)
        If (IsNumeric(Mid$(Str1, i, 1))) And i <> 1 Then
            chars(i - 1) = Mid$(Str1, i, 1)
        ElseIf (Not IsNumeric(Mid$(Str1, i, 1))) And i = 1 Then
            chars(i - 1) = ""
        Else
            chars(i - 1) = "*"
        End If
    Next

    Mathstr = Join(chars, "")
    MsgBox Application.Evaluate(Mathstr)
End Sub
```